# Android don't know how to play youtube URLs by using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, url, youtube, extract, exoplayer

I get default Youtube url from user like this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" and I need to play it, but exoplayer can't read it. I need to somehow extract it.

I tried doing it by using [youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor). I use this function in activity:

```
fun extractYouTube(context: Context, url: String, onSuccess: (String) -> Unit) {
    object : YouTubeExtractor(context) {
        override fun onExtractionComplete(
            ytFiles: SparseArray<YtFile>?,
            videoMeta: VideoMeta?
        ) {
            ytFiles?.get(22)?.url?.let {
                onSuccess(it)
            }
        }

    }.extract(url, true, true)
}
```

But onExtractionComplete ytFile was always null.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing my answer i just warn you not to use any other library if your publishing your app in playstore or anywhere else according to google terms its not legal way to get the youtube videos. but these library are created for personal purpose so i think your asking for same  but if you want to use youtube and publish in official store then use [google youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)

Here is your answer :

can you check what shows inside logcat by passing url to logger
like this

```
fun extractYouTube(context: Context, url: String, onSuccess: (String) -> Unit) {
    object : YouTubeExtractor(context) {
        override fun onExtractionComplete(
            ytFiles: SparseArray<YtFile>?,
            videoMeta: VideoMeta?
        ) {
            ytFiles?.get(22)?.url?.let {
                onSuccess(it)
            }
        }

    }.extract(url, true, true)
          Log.d("youtubeurl",url);
}
```

I have only java code :

```
String trailerUrl = "";
sendtoytextractor(trailerUrl )



private void sendtoytextractor(String trailerUrl) {
        new YouTubeExtractor(this) {

            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int itag = 22;
                    String downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
                    PlayTrailer(downloadUrl);
                }
            }
        }.extract(trailerUrl);
    }

private void PlayTrailer(String downloadUrl) {
        exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
                .build();
        DataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "KAIOS"));
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory, extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(downloadUrl)));
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

-> First get your youtube url and pass it to the string  then create a
method where it contain the url
->  here youtube will extract the video and get the mp4 link for you catch that link and pass it to exoplayer media source
->  here do the normal player process your video should be start playing